# Runtime error 1004: initialization of data source failed (issue between 32 and 64 bit Excel version)

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, 32bit-64bit, oledbconnection

I have this code (not written by me) and it always worked well for its purpose. Since my Office version has been upgraded from 2010 32-bit to 2016 64-bit it stopped working, resulting in a Runtime Error 1004: initialization of data source failed. I tested it on a computer with the 32-bit version of Excel 2016 and it worked! Since I'm not familiar with querytables, I can't find why it is occurring. Could someone give me a light? I found similar problems on the internet, but couldn't fix the problem with the purposed solutions.

Here is the code. It stops at ".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False":

```
Sub Importar_Prime()
    Sheets("Estoque Polo").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.QueryTable.Delete
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\temp\esce014.xls;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Proper" _
        , _
        "ties=""HDR=YES;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;" _
        , _
        "Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Databas" _
        , _
        "e Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=Fal" _
        , "se;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False"), _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("Plan1$")
        .Name = "esce014_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .SourceDataFile = "C:\temp\esce014.xls"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:7").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Replace What:="_", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1="""",""ZZZ"",RC[-12])"
    Range("P1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("P1:Q1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto Reference:="R3000C16"
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range("P1:Q3000").Select
    Range("P3000").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("P1:Q3000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("Q:Q").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("P:Q").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Cells.Replace What:="ZZZ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Sheets("Relatório").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, *every single line* not in the `With` block relies on the ActiveSheet/Selection!

Comment: try installing the x64 version of the OLEDB drivers: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: According to this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5b29496-d6a1-4ecf-b1a4-5550d80b84b6/microsoftjetoledb40-32bit-and-64bit?forum=adodotnetdataproviders, " Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not supported for 64-bit OS"